# 360 controller restarts my PC

Tags: usb, xbox360, shutdown, game-controller

When I connect my wired Xbox 360 controller to a USB port on my PC, the computer shuts down instantly. I have no idea why this happens. It used to work.

I have tried to other ports, and I can connect my 2 matcatz fightsticks fine.

Comment: Make sure you have disabled the automatically restart on system failure "feature"( see for example : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/automatic-restart-windows-7.htm ). Side note: when XP first came out Microsoft and their sock puppets said they got rid of those annoying blue screens. That's because (by default) they made the computer shut down instead of showing them.

Comment: ok, i was getting a blue screen of death. i get this stop messege, dont know if it helps. STOP: 0x0000007e (0x0000000000000000, x0FFFFF880031A89C8, 0xFFFFF880031A8230

Comment: no indication of a module?

Comment: Probably not your problem, but related: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327863

Answer (score 1):

- Follow the steps in this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906347)
- Try installing a new copy of the driver [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows)
- Try connecting the controller into a different device. If it shutsdown that device, it might be a short in the controller. If it doesn't, you might not have enough power on the USB bus to power everything. In the latter case, unplug some unused devices on your PC before plugging in the controller.

Comment: ok it works on my laptop. but i have a 850W PSU on my pc, so could that really be the issue?

Comment: Probably not, since I see a lot of people complaining about similar issues. Is it XP ? If so, SP2 or SP3 ?  Can you check the system events?  Does your computer power off or restart ?

Comment: In other news, what on earth are you doing with an 850W PSU!? Do you have 5 video cards and 20 cores?

Comment: im on windows 7 64bit

Comment: tried installing 64bit drivers but i got 'setup error: not enough storage', i have 15GB free

Comment: Try installing the drivers at the link in the answer (just changed the link). If it still happens, check your system events.

Comment: Uh..weird. Try right clicking and running as administrator.

Comment: really strange, i installed the one from the new link, and it still shutdown.

Comment: Check your event log. I don't have a windows 7 PC in front of me so I'm not quite sure where the option is..

Comment: is this what i want? 'The Windows Error Reporting Service service entered the stopped state.' 'Service Control Manager'

Comment: Not quite, you're looking for some kind of error related to the driver.

Comment: any idea what source i should look for? there are thousands of events here

Comment: Something that looks like the driver name. What happens if you leave the controller plugged in while it's booting up? Does it work ?

Comment: no it goes to the windows splash screen then reboots.

Comment: Hrm. I'm going to go home and try plugging mine in. I'll give you more info when I have my machine in front of me.

Comment: Sorry, I never came back to mention that everything worked for me when I tried it out. I even uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers several times, but worked like a charm each time. Did you ever get yours to work?